# How to access config object in OpenUI5 Manifest.json

Tags: config, custom-component, sapui5

I am using the OpenUI5 framework to create a custom component. I want to access some config settings that I set in the component's manifest.json file. According to the [documentation](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/docs/guide/be0cf40f61184b358b5faedaec98b2da.html) I can create some name/value pairs within a "config" object nested inside the "sap.ui5" object:

> config:   Static configuration; specify the name-value pairs that you need in your component.

and i should be able to access those settings from my component like so:

```js
this.getMetadata().getManifest();
```

After calling that method and inspecting the returned sap.ui5 object in the console, the only objects available are "dependencies", "extends", "models", and "rootView".  No "config" object.

How can i access my config settings in the manifest.json?

snippet of manifest.json:

```json
...
"sap.ui5": {
    "_version": "1.1.0",
    "rootView": {
        "viewName": "ctg.openui5.components.webmap.view.Map",
        "type": "HTML"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "minUI5Version": "1.30",
        "libs": {
            "sap.m": {}
        }
    },
    "models": {
        "i18n": {
            "type": "sap.ui.model.resource.ResourceModel",
            "settings": {
                "bundleName": "ctg.openui5.components.webmap.i18n.i18n"
            }
        }
    },
    "config": {
        "lat": 1,
        "lon": 2
    }
}
```

Comment: I made a minimum example where it works. What UI5 version are you using? Where are you calling `getManifest`?

Comment: @Marc: I am using the CDN version of UI5.  Not sure what I was doing wrong previously, but calling this.getMetadata().getManifest()  (where 'this' is the component) is now returning an object with a 'config' object nested inside the sap.ui5 object.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on the [documentation](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/api/symbols/sap.ui.core.Component.html#getManifestEntry), you can use

```js
this.getManifestEntry("/sap.ui5/config");
```

in you Component to get the *config* object in your Manifest.

Comment: Thank for this informative post. Is there such a thing we can change a value in manifest.json, also? Something like this.setMainfestEntry("/sap.ui5/config/lat", 2); ???